# capturing pipe exit status in R

Tags: linux, r, pipe, exit-code

I am using R's `pipe()` function to capture output from a shell command, but I would also like to get the exit code from the command.

I know that I could use `system2` here, but I need the advantage of a pipe i.e. the ability to process output in a streaming fashion.

I am considering writing my own library to wrap the `popen()` and `pclose()` C functions to take advantage of the fact that `pclose()` returns the exit status, but maybe this can be avoided.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

**Note**

There are certainly ways to do this with temporary files, named pipes, etc but I would ideally like to avoid these workarounds. I am willing to compile a shared library with an R->C function in it (and I'm even willing to copy-paste part of the R source code), but I'm not willing to rebuild R.

**Update**

I started reading through the R source code and found the unchecked pclose call:

in `src/main/connections.c`:

```
static void pipe_close(Rconnection con)
{
    pclose(((Rfileconn)(con->private))->fp);
    con->isopen = FALSE;
}
```

I tried going forward with the approach of implementing an `R_pclose` C function that duplicates the R code for `close()` but saves this return value. I unfortunately ran into this static variable in `src/main/connections.c`

```
static Rconnection Connections[NCONNECTIONS];
```

Since I'd have to run `objcopy --globalize-symbol=Connections libR.so /path/to/my/libR.so` anyway to access the variable, it looks like my best solution is to rebuild R with my own patch to capture the pclose return value.

Comment: You could use a named pipe (aka. fifo) to use streaming processing with `system2`, but that would mean passing `wait=FALSE` to that function, so you still wouldn't get the exit status.

Answer (score 1):

Ugly hack: you can wrap your command call into a small shell script which writes the exit code of its child to some temporary file. So when the stream has ended, you could wait until that file has non-zero size, then read the status from there. I hope someone comes up with a better solution, but at least this is a kind of solution.